# How to delay ntp.service start?

Tags: ntp

My laptop has Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS installed. I mainly use the wifi connection; however I installed UM with an ethernet connection. Now during boot up there's a delay in resolving ntp servers. After login there's no problem. I want to delay ntp.service start and don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

You can use systemd timer.

*your.timer*

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts ntp after boot

[Timer]
OnBootSec=60s
Unit=ntp.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also you should disable *ntp.service* and enable *your.timer*